# How to add params to form_for, but don't want to add them to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models named `quiz` and `question`

`quiz has_many questions`

I want to add params to the `quiz` new `form_for`, so I can use them in `quizs_controller`. Such as `from` and `to`, the user can input the integer to get the questions in the `from xx to xx` range.

But I don't want to add the `from` and `to` params in the `quiz` model.

I want to know how to implement this.

Thanks.

**Edit**

quizzes/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @quiz] do |f| %>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title, "Title:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Range:" %>

    <!-- I want to know how to add `from` and `to` params here -->

  </div>


  <%= f.submit "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", admin_quizzes_path %>

<% end %>
```

quizzes_controller.rb

```
def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new
end

def create
  @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
  @questions = @quiz.questions
  # And I want to gain the `from` and `to` here to **FILTER** THE questions

  if @quiz.save
    redirect_to admin_quizzes_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Why in a form for new question you want to add filters on getting another questions? Either I haven't get you or you haven't properly formulate your question

Comment: Maybe you meant "I want to add params to the `QUIZ` new `form_for`"???

Comment: Sorry, it's my typo. There are `quiz`, not `quesiton`.

Comment: Am I right that your goal now is to get 2 params `from` and `to` in your `quiz#create` method, that will not be a part of quiz? (to double check, that I think about what you really need)

Comment: And it would be perfect if you paste your current `from` and target actions codes

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's I wanted.

Comment: @AntonTkachov I edited the question.

Comment: Updated my answer according to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your form add:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_for :from %>
  <%= number_field_tag :from, :class => "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Same for `to`.

In your controller you can reference them as:

```
def create
  @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
  @from = params[:from]
end
```

Whether this worked for you?

Comment: Yes, that's I wanted. Thank you very much.